# Can we generate Connection String for ODBC, JDBC, PHP and ADO.Net of Azure SQL Database using python SDK?

Tags: python, python-2.7, azure, connection-string, azure-sql-database

I want to generate Connection String for ODBC, JDBC, PHP and ADO.Net using python for Azure SQL Database. I can see that option on Azure portal, Is there any way to generate those connection string programmatically? Any thing ASM, ARM or REST is available for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I known, I think you can't generate connection string using Python for Azure SQL Database, because you can't get the user and password required for the connection string via SQL Database [REST APIs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt163571.aspx) or [classic REST APIs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn505719.aspx).

However, you can generate the connection string without user and password as connection string template via using the REST APIs `Get Database`, `Get Server`, `List All Databases` & `List All Servers` to extract the attributes `server name` & `database name`.